# How to find exact match in MySQL version 8.x

Tags: mysql-8.0

I am trying to find an exact word from the database using the below syntax.

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM node_field_data node LEFT JOIN book book ON node.nid = book.nid LEFT JOIN node__body body ON node.nid = body.entity_id LEFT JOIN node__field_rule_number rule_number ON node.nid = rule_number.entity_id LEFT JOIN node__field_effective_date effective_date ON node.nid = effective_date.entity_id LEFT JOIN node__field_end_date end_date ON node.nid = end_date.entity_id WHERE ( node.title REGEXP :text OR body.body_value REGEXP :text OR rule_number.field_rule_number_value REGEXP :text ); Array ( [:text] => [[:<:]]law[[:>:]] )
```

it gives me the below error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3685 Illegal argument to a regular
>   expression.

Could any one please tell me where i am making the mistake the below is code where i am trying to find exact match

```
if ($exact) {
            $text = "";
            foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
                $text = $text . preg_quote($keyword) . " ";
            }
            $text = preg_replace('/\s+$/', '', $text);
            $params[':text'] = "[[:<:]]".$text."[[:>:]]";

        }
```

Comment: Please include the full PHP code behind this error.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have added the code could you please check and let me know

Comment: Did you resolve this? What's your *exact* version of MySQL? 8.?.?

Answer (score 0):

check this
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-compatibility

[[:<:]] not supported in mysql8

select * from Table where field regexp '\\bmatch1|match2\\b';